# Combining XSL documents

Tags: xml, xslt

I have used an XSL to convert a docbook document into dita.  The conversion was successful, bu there are unwanted artifacts which remain.  I've gotten rid of a few of them, but I have saved these changes in another XSL which is run after the conversion.  My question is:  Is it possible to combine this into a single XSL?  when I've tried adding the  code after the docbook2dita.xsl it seemed to have no effect, am I missing something?

Also I was thinking of changing the xref that were being used in docbook, to related links in DITA.  Is this a good idea?  what problems have ppl run into with xref that related links needed to be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to apply two or more transformations in sequence (chain), each operating on the result of the previous one.

**Here is how to chain together two transformations in XSLT 2.0** (the XSLT 1.0 example is similar, but one needs to use the `xxx:node-set()` function on each intermediary result):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vPass1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="id" mode="#default pass2">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vPass1" mode="pass2"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="2*."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num/text()" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:value-of select="1+."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:

```
<nums>
 <num>1</num>
 <num>2</num>
 <num>3</num>
 <num>4</num>
 <num>5</num>
</nums>
```

two transformations are applied in a sequence. The result of the first transformation is a new XML document in which the value of each `num/text()` node is twice the value of the original `num/text()` node. The second transformation is applied on this intermediary result and its action is to add `1` to every `num/text()` node and to produce this result as the new corresponding `num/text()' node.

**Thus the comulative result is that every `$n` (the value of every `num/text()` node) is transformed to `2*$n+1`** :

```
<nums>
   <num>3</num>
   <num>5</num>
   <num>7</num>
   <num>9</num>
   <num>11</num>
</nums>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to combine this into a
>   single XSL?

It's posible to express this in a single transformation with multiple stylesheets modules.

If you don't know how DITA XSLT works, the best way would be: to use `import` declaration for XSLT DITA, and to declare your own rules.

**Edit**: Example. Suppose this stylesheet `base.xsl`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="parent">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="child">
        <b>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </b>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <child>1</child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child>2</child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child>3</child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child>4</child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <p>
        <b>1</b>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>2</b>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>3</b>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>4</b>
    </p>
</html>
```

Now, this stylesheet ussing `import`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:import href="base.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template match="parent">
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <div>
        <b>1</b>
    </div>
    <div>
        <b>2</b>
    </div>
    <div>
        <b>3</b>
    </div>
    <div>
        <b>4</b>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Are transformations applied sequentially, or are they all concurrent?

Comment: @Ace: With this method you are declaring **one** trasformation with several modules. So, it's all concurrent because there is no sequence.

Comment: So if I had like 8 transformations (the first being docbook2dita.xsl, then the rest order doesn't matter), do I have one 'master' .XSL that imports each of them? or have each import one other one, so it's like a chain of XSL that gets called when the first one gets called?

Comment: @Ace: Order or chain does matter. Suppose this chain (with -> meaning import) *A -> B -> C*: if the last two have a template matching a node, only the template from B will be applied, because it has a higher import precedence. Now suppose this chain *A -> B, C*: if the last two have a template marching a node (with the same calculated priority) it would be an error, but by error recovery mechanism, processor could apply the template declared lastly.

Comment: Alright,  Whats the best way of combining these transformations then?

Comment: @Ace: It depends of use case. Think of this like about class inheritance.

Comment: Well all I need is to run docbook2dita.xsl first, then 8 other xsl after that to fix the artifacts and stuff.  The order of the 8 xsl don't matter

Comment: If you are "fixing" things that you don't like in the default docbook2dita.xsl, that is what @Alejandro's suggestion of an `import` is useful for. You "inherit" the docbook2dita.xsl templates as a baseline and can just "override" the templates that you don't like to have them do things differently. It can all be done in a single transform and can be more efficient than running 8+ transforms to "fix" the output. Simply import the 8+ XSLT "modules" that create one virtual XSLT to do the work.